# Append string at end of every filename

Tags: rename

I want to add "_Test" at the end of every file name in my current directory. Version gives me `rename from util-linux 2.23.2`, I've tried `rename $ _Test *` and `rename 's/$/_Test' *` but when I list my files they have not been renamed.

Comment: Can you run `rename --help` to see which version of rename you have? The version number doesn't help me much. On my Ubuntu 16, `rename 's/$/_Test' *` prints an error message because the closing `/` is missing. After I fix this, the `_Test` is added as expected.

Comment: On my Centos server, `rename` doesn't support regular expressions. If that is your version, I am afraid you have to do with `mv` as suggested by the answer.

Comment: rename --help doesn't give much. Usage:
 rename [options] expression replacement file...

Options:
 -v, --verbose    explain what is being done
 -s, --symlink    act on symlink target

 -h, --help     display this help and exit
 -V, --version  output version information and exit For more details see rename(1).

Comment: It shows that your version is like my Centos version. On Ubuntu, `--help` mentions Perl expressions. Use `mv`.

Comment: Indeed mine is a CentOS linux. I would have never guessed that the command would work differently depending on the machine as other stack exchange answers seem to suggest using rename like this. So there is no way to append a word at the end of a filename using rename? Sounds like a pretty useless command if that is the case :P

Comment: I don't think it is possible with the version you have. Perhaps the developers thought that appending a string is such a trivial problem that they didn't bother addressing it. So `rename` may be useless for this particular task, but if you have to rename a non-empty string, it is quite useful.

Comment: Debian and it’s clones use the Perl-based “rename” while CentOS uses the one built with util-linux.  EPEL has “prename” which is the Perl rename.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have it, you can always roll your own like below:

```
perl -e '
  rename($_, s/$/__Test/r)
    for @ARGV;
' ./*
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for n in $(ls -1); do mv "$n" "$n"_Test; done
```

This will rename every file in the directory it is run.

Comment: [bash pitfall #1](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29) - just use `for n in *`

Comment: `for f in *; do mv "$f" "$f"_Test; done` did the trick, thanks both. If you're more used to python than bash I also like the python solution `for index, file in enumerate(os.listdir(dir)): os.rename(os.path.join(dir, file), os.path.join(dir, "{}_{}".format(file, 'Test')))` :D And I do wonder why the rename command does not work.

Comment: I am seriously question how do you deal with filtering then ie. (ls -p) would you suggest just dealing with scope after the fact.  This is an honest question I would like to know your thoughts on the issue.